# Gmailify vs simple forwarding. What's the difference?

Tags: gmail, outlook.com, email-forwarding

I have a main Google account and two other email addresses I'd like to manage through the main account. One is a second Gmail address and the other is a @outlook.com address.

I understand that I have two options:

1. Use Gmailify (possible for one email address only)
2. Forward each email address to the main one and add them as "Send mail as", so that I can send emails from them too.

Obviously, if I were to choose option 1 for one address, I'd have to choose 2 for the other as only one other email address can be "Gmailified".

Is there any important difference between the two options, or any difference at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between Gmailify and forwarding your mail is that Gmailify will import all your mail and also keep your accounts synchronised. That means that if you make changes to your imported mail (like label changes, reading, or starring emails) these changes will be exported back to your other account.

As you have correctly noted, only one account can be linked with Gmailify. Linking another Gmail account with Gmailify is not supported, so in your case you can only link your outlook account with Gmailify or use forwarding for both.

If you use Gmailify you will automatically get a "Send mail as" address configured for that account.

Comment: Thank you. In that case I think forwarding will do everything I need. I don't need old emails to be imported and I don't really need anything to be synchronized - just that all emails are forwarded and archived.

Comment: There is one catch though: it's impossible to send an email from another Gmail account ("Send mail as") without leaving some trace in the email of the main account used to send it. Not sure if Gmailify would solve that. This is not a problem with non-Gmail addresses, where you can specify an SMTP server other than Google's.

Answer (score 1):

Beware:
"Messages added using Gmailify do not get processed by the Gmail filters and do not get a label identifying the source account.  There really is no way around that, other than running the filters manually or setting up a Google Apps Script."
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/c_hll4lOlVQ/3MpTZqLHAgAJ

I can confirm that this is unfortunately true